# How can I specify the fileds to insert in MongoDB Output in Logstash

Tags: mongodb, logstash

I've below in output config, but it inserts the raw data in MongoDB. How can I insert only a few selected fields? For InfluxDB, we have an attribute data_points with which I can do it, but MongoDB plugin doesn't seem to have any such feature.

```
            mongodb {
                collection => "logs"
                database => "test"
                uri => "mongodb://localhost:27017"
                codec => line 
                    {
                    enable_metric => "false"
                    format => "data1:%{val1}, data2:%{val2}, data3:%{val3}"
                    }
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Logstash [prune filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-prune.html) for this. The prune filter's `whitelist_names` setting allows you to removes all fields that are not enumerated in the array.

```
filter {
  prune {
    whitelist_names => ["field1", "field2", "field3"]
  }
}
```

Something that I think is really cool about the prune filter is that it also allows you to input regular expressions - and removes any field that does not match the regular expression. So instead of the above, you could have:

```
filter {
  prune {
    whitelist_names => ["^field\d+"]
  }
}
```

Another note: The prune filter does not come installed by default. You must run `bin/logstash-plugin install logstash-filter-prune`

Comment: Another note: if you want Logstash's added fields, like `@timestamp`, `tags`, or whatever, you have to enumerate those in the whitelist as well.

Comment: I tried this and it worked, but there is still something missing. I have tagged my sources as http and tcp,  and I've whitelisted them so that I can output them based on tag. The problem is I cant find a remove_field option anywhere in output to remove the type before inserting into db. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @RimmyMathew - you can add metadata fields https://www.elastic.co/blog/logstash-metadata corresponding to each 'type', and then remove the 'type' field. Then in the output, you would use the metadata to drive different documents to different outputs. I have written a blog post that demonstrates this approach at https://alexmarquardt.com/2018/08/31/using-logstash-to-drive-filtered-data-from-a-single-source-into-multiple-output-destinations/. Disclaimer: I am a Consulting Engineer at Elastic.